# What are some good software instruction/manual?

Tags: windows, documentation

I'm not sure if this is the right place to put a question but I believe this is an important issues need to be addressed to application developing.

I am trying to write an instruction manual for an desktop application I'm written, and didn't realized it is much harder than I thought. Does anyone encounter software instruction manual that are clear, concise and well written? I found most manual written for software are obscure , thick or difficult to follow.

Appreciated if someone can point to some software manual that is well versed so I can take it as reference to write good software instruction manual.

Comment: Thank you for closing off topic question. But at least tell me where it supposed to belong?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual for the Inform interactive fiction programming language](http://inform7.com/learn/man/WI_1_1.html) is a model of clarity.

Comment: Your link is broken, could you please add an alternative one?

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have done as you request.